# My SSD is acting like writing is locked. Not even bash dd command can achieve anything. How may I fix my drive?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, hardware-failure, formatting

I currently am using a 2.5" WD Blue 1Tb SSD for backups. I use Macrium Reflect on Windows to clone my C to it. Last time I attempted the clone, and because I don't do it often enough to remember every step, I forgot that Windows itself will ask if I'm sure about reformatting the drive after I've already gone through the two confirmation windows in Macrium Reflect about it. And Windows only asks this after Macrium Reflect reaches 1%.

Well, I set up the clone before going straight to bed when I forgot about that last confirmation, so it sat on 1% for around 8 hours and then in the morning when I discovered it and clicked yes Macrium Reflect said there was an error and it could not continue. From then on when trying to access the drive on Windows, Explorer would lock up even if I right-clicked it and Disk Manager would freeze if trying to access it (Macrium Reflect also freezes and doesn't load if it's connected). If I unplugged the drive, then Disk Manager would load its window fine.

So I decided to try my Linux machine. Using KDE Partition Manager, I was able to view the drive. The main partition I originally had on it was unallocated, but the system partition and lenovo-recovery(because I'm on a Thinkpad) were still there. Tried deleting all the partitions: failure. Tried resizing partitions: failure. Tried New Partition Table: said it succeeded, but nothing actually changed.

So then I resorted to bash commands. Tried `fdisk`, tried `wipefs` (this is the command KDE Partition Manager uses anyway so it was expected to fail), and then finally went the whole way and tried `sudo dd`.
First, I tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` like I saw online. Didn't change anything (dd never outputted failure, but it did)
Then I tried `bs=1M` and `bs=5G`. Neither changed anything.
So finally I tried doing it only to the leftover ntfs system partition (changed `of=/dev/sdb` to `of=/dev/sdb1`) which was 1.17 GB, using `bs=1G`.
Still nothing has changed.

Please help.

Comment: Can we see SMART (add to question)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Lenovo Support site and get the Disk Test App for your particular ThinkPad.

Download it to a bootable USB Key (Rufus is helpful).

Start with the Test App and test your disk.

The disk may have a hardware error (the test will tell you this).

If hardware errors, the drive needs to be replaced.

If not (if the disk is apparently good) then you have some other operating system damage and will very likely have to rebuild your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an NVMe SSD you should be able to check S.M.A.R.T. and see if the device switched itself to read only mode. AFAIK, SATA SSD's don't features an attribute to signal this state.

In case of NVMe, if read-only bit is set in the 'critical warning attribute' while no other critical errors apply the value for the attribute will be 0x08.

If you get a different non-zero value convert the value to binary using a calculator or an online tool like https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-binary.html.

The following critical warning flags can be set:

```
Bit 0: If set to ‘1’, then the available spare capacity has fallen below the threshold
Bit 1: If set to ‘1’, then a temperature is (> over temp threshold) or (< below temp threshold)
Bit 2: If set to ‘1’, then the NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded due to significant media related errors or any internal error that degrades NVM subsystemreliability.
Bit 3: If set to ‘1’, then the media has been placed in read only mode
Bit 4: If set to ‘1’, then the volatile memory backup device has failed. This field is only valid if the controller has a volatile memory backup solution.
```

So if we see for example 0x08, we convert to binary and get 00001000.

We start counting at last bit, the last bit being bit zero, so then bit 3 is set in this example. There may be additional bits set but you can still use below table to determine if the read-only bit was set.

```
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0 - bit
----------------
|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0
```

This is a firmware decision and resetting it requires a vendor specific command AFAIK. IOW your only option is to salvage the data from the SSD and replace it.

Example SMART output of a NVMe SSD in read-only mode:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x08  <<<< 
Temperature:                        25 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    486,334 [249 GB]
Data Units Written:                 476,639 [244 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,838,965
Host Write Commands:                3,809,355
Controller Busy Time:               45
Power Cycles:                       100
Power On Hours:                     25
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   25
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    17,200,105
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
```

Sources: https://media.kingston.com/support/downloads/MKP_521.6_SMART-DCP1000_attribute.pdf - Although this is a Kingston document it complies with NVMe specs. IOW, these attributes and their explanations apply to all NMVe SSD devices.